# Could someone explain what is Kafka Listener

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am trying to run kafka server using docker (docker-compose.yml file below), and I get the following error:

```
ERROR: No listener or advertised hostname configuration provided in environment.
       Please define KAFKA_LISTENERS / (deprecated) KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
```

I have done research, and I found out that `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` would describe the server hostname or ip address. And it is deprecated.

If not set, `KAFKA_LISTENERS` should instead be configured.

Could someone explain to me what are these variable, and what is their purpose ?

docker-compose.yml file

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-1.1.1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    links:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: 'true'
```

Comment: Please check this https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Hi check the above link for deep understanding of the mechanism,  for your situation just add the KAFKA_LISTENERS suggested , PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092 for example